Do timer interrupts (STM32) work in the KEIL simulator
A question from a beginner.
I'm currently studying interrupts and timers. The systick in keil (on the simulator) for ARM CM3 works fine.
There are problems with timers (TIM1, TIM2, etc.) on STM 32. The code is compiled and run, but it does not stop inside the handler during debugging.
Question: Do timer interrupts work in the KEIL simulator or not?
Example:
#include "stm32f10x.h" 
#include "stm32f10x_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f10x_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f10x_tim.h"
#define TIMER_PRESCALER 720
uint16_t previousState;
GPIO_InitTypeDef port;
TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef timer;
void initAll()
{
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);
    GPIO_StructInit(&port);
    port.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    port.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
    port.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &port);
    TIM_TimeBaseStructInit(&timer);
    timer.TIM_Prescaler = TIMER_PRESCALER - 1;
    timer.TIM_Period = 50;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &timer);
}
 
int main()
{
    __enable_irq();
    initAll();
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM4, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM4_IRQn);
    while(1)
    {
        __NOP();
    } 
}

void TIM4_IRQHandler()
{ 
    if (previousState == 0)
    {
        previousState = 1;
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_0);
        timer.TIM_Period = 50;
        TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &timer); 
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM4, TIM_IT_Update);
    }
    else
    {
        previousState = 0;
        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_0);
        timer.TIM_Period = 250;
        TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &timer); 
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM4, TIM_IT_Update);
    } 
}

UPD:  If you select in KEIL:
Peripherals -> Core Peripherals -> Nested Vectored Interrupt Controller
and check the Enable and Pending boxes, then you will be able to get into the handler.

You can test it by manually triggering interrupt from software. Do NVIC->SWI=TIM4_IRQn; in main, after the interrupt has been enabled. It should go straight to the interrupt handler. If it does, then it's your timer that's misconfigured.
